# Is it possible to combine these 2 queries to get back 2 result sets?

Tags: mysql

I almost never work with MYSQL so excuse the basic question but...

Is it possible to combine 2 queries in MYSQL and send different result sets? I have the following 2 queries that are identical except the `request_date` value is different. Running the first gives `100` and running the second gives `200`. Is it possible to combine them both and get 100 and 200 back respectively?

I don't mean I want to get back 300, I still want to get back the totals for each day separately. Is that possible to do in one query?

```
SELECT SUM(revenue - spend) as total_profit FROM `profit_by_campaign` WHERE campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' AND request_date = '2017-11-03'

SELECT SUM(revenue - spend) as total_profit FROM `profit_by_campaign` WHERE campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' AND request_date = '2017-11-02'
```

Comment: You might try: SELECT SUM(revenue - spend) as total_profit FROM `profit_by_campaign` WHERE campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' AND request_date = '2017-11-03' OR request_date = '2017-11-02';  You might also consider an 'IN' statement if you end up adding more dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT request_date, SUM(revenue - spend) as total_profit 
FROM `profit_by_campaign` 
WHERE campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' 
  AND (request_date = '2017-11-03' OR request_date = '2017-11-02') 
GROUP BY request_date
```

Comment: Should use `IN` operatior like `AND request_date  IN ('2017-11-03', '2017-11-02')`

Comment: good edit to have added the selection of `request_date` too, so that you can know where the row comes from

Comment: Yes, just added request_date a minute ago